# Wildfly module classloading

Tags: java, wildfly-11, classloading

I have come across a rather curious issue with wildfly classloading. I have a java-ee webapp, structured as follows:

```
some.ear
+- some.war
+- EJBs.jar
```

both the war and the jar require some spring classes to function properly. I defined a spring module containing the relevant classes. Within `jboss-deployment-structure` I have a section as follows:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <module name="org.springframework.spring-web"/>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

After launching my webapp, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when deploying the war-archive.
If I add an additional section

```
<sub-deployment name="some.war">
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <module name="org.springframework.spring-web"/>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```

it works.

My understanding is, that every module from the main-deployment section should also be visible in all sub-deployments.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each sub-deployment would need it's own set of module dependencies. If you were to include the module libraries in the `EAR/lib` directory instead of creating a module then you'd not need to add the module dependency for each sub-deployment.

Comment: To clarify: If i put a lib in /lib it is available to all modules. If I put it into the `<deployment>` section (insteadof the `<subdeployment>` section), where is it visible?

Comment: If you add it as a module and use the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` you need to add the dependencies to each deployment and sub-deployment that needs a dependency on the module.